# What does this assembly code do and why is it used?

Tags: assembly, att

**ATT syntax.**

I've noticed that library routines in C often use the following snippet of assembly code:

```
call next
next:
popl %eax
```

- What value is %eax storing here and why is it getting popped?
- What's the purpose of this snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462221/the-return-address-in-the-assembly-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The return address in the assembly code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462221/the-return-address-in-the-assembly-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the value of %eax after this sequence of instructions?
>
> call
>   next
>
> next: popl %eax
>
> Whatever the address of next is
>
> (the memory address where popl instruction is) Note: this is NOT the
>   PC, but it is related to it
>
> – PC is the address of the next instruction to be executed; %eax now
>   has address of most recently executed instruction (the popl)

[See](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aO_ahr1IqNFUJ%3awww.cs.umd.edu/class/summer2011/cmsc216/lectures/Week7/14-Assembly.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShqj0x_qSe9SNmxglYRsd1__RNhQZktvLBsvgnD7iVUX_CPbck0AHUl0jMxyWXQXitjH0rfFbtPzkCWVzbVbskROpiBYcSl1YVdzD3hnMdd5L9dtPUf_7uFwPKCHbW_h9lIwnmA&sig=AHIEtbRPColEaVEgFcOZJYMoZWUI0Pz60w)

Comment: I know %eax is used as the register that returns a function's value. Does it also store the address of certain instructions after they are executed then?

Answer (score 2):

It gives you the current value of the program counter (PC).  That is, you get the address of the current instruction that is executing.

Here's an interesting article that talks about using that snippet vs doing it with C: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/16/317157.aspx

Comment: You could add the summary: "It's bad, because it causes an in-balance in call vs. ret statements, which breaks CPU's return address prediction logic."